# SSO from VB.NET web application to ROR web site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vb.net, single-sign-on

I am supporting a website that is built on ruby on rails . Now there is another web application on VB.NET in which one link to be provided that will seamlessly lead the authenticated users of ROR website, who have logged in to the VB.NET web application,to the homepage of ROR website.

```
That is,I need to implement SSO between VB.NET and ROR. USER'S EMAIL ID  to be used as the authentication parameter in this.
```

I know only the basics about VB.NET and ROR so I am quite clueless on this. The ROR website is using mysql database and mongrel server.

I googled and found some topics on OAuth,OpenID and RubyCAS but failed to understand how they can be implemented to meet my needs,if at all.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.